# Fix paths in dylib files using install_name_tool

Tags: macos, dynamic-linking, dylib, otool, install-name-tool

I'm trying to compile my C++ project after updating OS to El Capitan. However, I faced a few snags along the way:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: pathB/libIceUtil.34.dylib
Referenced from: pathA/libSlice.34.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

The problem is that `pathB` doesn't exist. When I run `otool -L pathA/libIceUtil.34.dylib`, I get

```
pathA/libIceUtil.34.dylib:
pathB/libIceUtil.34.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

`install_name_tool -change pathB/libIceUtil.34.dylib pathA/libIceUtil.34.dylib pathA/libIceUtil.34.dylib` didn't solve the problem. An [article](http://qin.laya.com/tech_coding_help/dylib_linking.html) mentions using `libtool`. Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What do you want it changed to?

Comment: @trojanfoe  `/Volumes/Data/builder/` prefix --> `/Users/xeroqu/lib/`prefix. I modified the question as well.

Comment: Don't you want it relative to the executable?

Comment: @trojanfoe not necessarily. I'd like to fix these paths...

Comment: `install_name_tool` is the thing to use.

Comment: @trojanfoe I tried that already - didn't fix. Updated the question again

Comment: Having a similar problem that I think I've sorted. What did otool -L report when run on `libIceUtil.34.dylib`? In my case, the target library had moved but still thought it was in the old location, which seemed to cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `install_name_tool -change` is not correct (it doesn't match what `otool -L` printed).  Use:

```
install_name_tool -change \
    /Volumes/Data/builder/Proj/gcc4/thirdparty/Ice-3.4.2-x86_64/lib/libIceUtil.34.dylib \
    /Users/xeroqu/lib/Proj/gcc4/thirdparty/Ice-3.4.2-x86_64/lib/libIceUtil.34.dylib \
    /Users/xeroqu/lib/Proj/gcc4/thirdparty/Ice-3.4.2-x86_64/lib/libIceUtil.34.dylib
```

Comment: you're right and thus +1. However, I made a terrible mistake by copying, changing the project name and pasting it here - so the answer is not what I'm looking for. I simplified the question this time. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest.  I have successfully used `install_name_tool` to fix such issues in the past. There is a chance it relates to dependent libraries in the library itself...

Comment: Funny thing is that it works w/o problems for executables, but not for dylibs. Thanks for the hints